# Characterizing product topology using the continuity of component functions

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I am trying to prove that

> for the topological spaces $(X_i, \mathcal T_i)$'s the product topology on $\prod_i X_i$ is the unique topology $\mathcal T_\Pi$ such that for any topological space $(Y, \mathcal T)$ and any function $f\colon (Y, \mathcal T)\to (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T_\Pi)$, we have that $f$ is continuous if and only if each $\pi_i\circ f\colon (Y, \mathcal T)\to (X_i, \mathcal T_i)$ is continuous.

I am almost sure that my proof below works. But I would appreciate if someone can confirm it.

My proof attempt:

**Showing that $\mathcal T_\Pi$ is such a topology:**
"$\Rightarrow$" follows since $\pi_i$'s are continuous for the product topology and the fact that function composition preserves continuity.

For "$\Leftarrow$", we show that the inverse images of the (usual) subbase sets of $\mathcal T_\Pi$ are open. Let $U\in\mathcal T_{i_0}$ and consider $\pi_{i_0}^{-1}(U)$. Then $f^{-1}(\pi_{i_0}^{-1}(U)) = (\pi_{i_0}\circ f)^{-1}(U)$ which is open since $\pi_{i_0}\circ f$ is continuous.

**Showing uniqueness:**
Let $\mathcal T'$ be another such topology on $\prod_i X_i$.

To show that $\mathcal T'\subseteq \mathcal T_\Pi$, we show that the identity function $\iota\colon (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T_\Pi)\to (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T')$ is continuous. It follows if all $\pi_i\circ \iota = \pi_i\colon (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T_\Pi)\to (X_i, \mathcal T_i)$ are continuous, which is indeed true for the product topology.

To show that $\mathcal T_\Pi\subseteq\mathcal T'$, we show that the (usual) subbase of $\mathcal T_\Pi$ is included in $\mathcal T'$. Consider $U\in \mathcal T_{i_0}$. We show that $\pi_{i_0}^{-1}(U)\in \mathcal T'$. It will follow if $\pi_{i_0}\colon (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T')\to (X_{i_0}, \mathcal T_{i_0})$ is continuous, which will follow if all $\pi_i\circ\iota = \pi_i\colon (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T')\to (X_i, \mathcal T_i)$ are continuous, which follows if $\iota\colon (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T')\to (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T')$ is continuous, which is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof is correct and almost optimal. You could make it a few words shorter if you used at the end of the proof the fact that product topology is the coarsest topology for which all the projections are continuous. You can do it this way:

(...) To show that $\mathcal T_\Pi\subseteq\mathcal T'$, we need to prove that all the projections $\pi_{i_0}\colon (\prod_i X_i, \mathcal T')\to (X_{i_0}, \mathcal T_{i_0})$ are continuous, which will follow if all (...)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed that's some possible shortening.